# Citrix Web Interface - How to get back Native Embedded Client functionality?

Tags: web, citrix, interface

Sometime after Citrix Server 4.6, they removed the ability to use the Native *Embedded* client. The problem is that we want their application to stay within the browser window rather than seamless or in a seperate window. This use to be possible with older versions, but now with a Citrix Server 5.0+ server this option seems to have disappeared. Any idea how to get it back, or any example of a workaround? (I'm thinking a "simple" web interface which enumerates the applications and just uses the Citrix ActiveX control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Citrix has done away with that functionality, which I believe required ActiveX and IE6. This is mostly due to the security and compatibility issues involved with ActiveX's implementation in IE6, which has been completely revamped.